# How to keep data for different guilds/servers for Discord Bots

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am currently undertaking a project in which I am trying to make a RPG for a discord bot. I am currently struggling with how to implement a way to keep data for different servers separate. For example, I'm trying to store the location of the party for each server. I have tried testing moving from 'town' to 'forest'. It works on the server that the command is used, but all other servers that the bot is on also have their location updated to 'forest'. Since I'm new to c# as well I am struggling to work out a way to keep the location being updated on each server.

A possible solution would be to store an object for each guild in an array and reference it whenever guild specific data is required, however this doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

What would be the best way to achieve data separation between guilds?

MAIN

```
    using Discord;
    using Discord.Commands;
    using Discord.WebSocket;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TestBot2.Modules;

    namespace TestBot2
    {
        class Program
        {
    static void Main(string[] args){
         new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _command;
    private IServiceProvider _service;

    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _command = new CommandService();
        _service = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_command)
            .BuildServiceProvider();




        string botToken = *** BOT TOKEN ***;

        //event subscription
        _client.Log += Log;


        await RegisterCommandAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, botToken);

        await _client.StartAsync();



        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);

        return null;
    }

    public async Task RegisterCommandAsync()
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;

        await _command.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;




        if (!(message is SocketUserMessage) || message.Author.IsBot) {
            return;
        }
        int argPos = 1;

        if (message.HasStringPrefix("cf!", ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))
        {

            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

            var result = await _command.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos+1, _service);

            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);


        }
    }
}
```

}

UTILITY

```
   static string location = "town";            //curent loc
    static string[] locations =                 //array of vlaid loc
        {
            "town", "forest"
        };
    int[,] travelMtx = new int[,]               //distance matrix
   {
        {0,2 },
        {2,0 }
   };


    public string D6()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string reply;
        reply = Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(1, 7));
        return reply;
    }

    public string charName(string charowner = "")
    {
        string charname;

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = [FILE LOCATION]

        conn.Open();
        String my_query = "SELECT CharName FROM Chars WHERE CharOwner='" + charowner + "'";
        Console.WriteLine(my_query);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_query, conn);
        charname = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.Write(charname);
        return charname;
    }

    public string usermention(string user = "")
    {
        return user;

    }

    public string getLoc()
    {
        return Utility.location;
    }

    public void setLoc(string location)
    {
        Utility.location = location;
    }

    public bool checkLoc(string dest)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < locations.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dest.ToLower() == locations[i])
            {
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int travelTime(string location, string dest)
        {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < locations.Length; i++)
        {
            if (location.ToLower() == locations[i])
            {
                x = i;
            }
            if (dest.ToLower() == locations[i])
            {
                y= i;
            }
        }
           return travelMtx[x,y];
        }
    }
}
```

TRAVEL

```
public class Travel : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("Travel")]
    public async Task PingAsync(string dest = "")
    {
        Utility Util = new Utility();

        string loc = Util.getLoc();
        int travelTime = 0;


        if (Util.checkLoc(dest) == true)
        {
            travelTime = Util.travelTime(loc, dest);
        }

        Util.setLoc(dest);
        await ReplyAsync("you are now in " + dest + " it took " + travelTime + " days" );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to store it together with the serverip, so that you can ask for `CharOwner='" + charowner + "'"` and `ServerIp='" + serverip + "'"` in you `WHERE` part of the sql.

It's just a guess, but maybe it works. :)

Comment: Discord servers aren't really distinguish by a IP, but by a `ulong` identifier instead.  But this does sound like the best solution.
Maybe you could elaborate a bit more on how to properly achieve this, and why it would be a good option

Comment: Wait, I meant server id. That's my fault, I'm sorry!